# To Extract data from text file using c++98 linux

Tags: linux, text, text-extraction, data-extraction, c++98

I am trying extract some lines from plain text file. where it contains list of shell script executables with some generic keys for that particular sh file. the required data need to extract from that file should exclude .sh file name and MH_TEST keys.

for ex: if my file abc.lst contains

```
     Cable_pull1.sh
       MH_TEST             PAR
       DUAL_DOMAIN         yes
       CAMARO_STORAGE      YES
    
     Flagship.sh
        MH_TEST            NOR
        10_Flags           yes


      Domain_Distibute.sh
        MH_TEST            NOR
        fast_path          YES
        heavy_IO           YES
```

the requested data needed to extract from above file **abc.lst** file is below,
if file name passed is  "**Cable_pull1.sh**"

```
   DUAL_DOMAIN         yes
   CAMARO_STORAGE      YES
```

if file name is passed "**Flagship.sh**", expected output is below,

```
   10_Flags           yes
```

Below is the code i am trying to get result, where i am kind of lost to extract the required information, please help me with this to extract information i am looking for

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;
    
    bool findWord(string Filename, string const& find)
    {
            cout<<"Filename:"<<Filename<<"\t"<<"find:"<<find<<endl;
            ifstream iFile(Filename.c_str());
            if(!iFile)
            {
                    cerr<<"File not opened!\n";
                    return false;
            }
    
            char c;
            string content;
            while(iFile.get(c) )
            {
                    if(c != '\n')
                    {
                            content += c;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       content = ""; //reset string after flag ',' was found
                    }
    
                    if(content == find)
                            return true;
            }
            cout<<"content:"<<content<<endl;
            return false;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
       if(!findWord("abc.lst","Cable_pull1.sh"))
          cout<<"failed"<<endl;
        else
         cout<<"success"<<endl;
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, now it seems to compile. Does `Cable_pull1.sh` have spaces to the left of it inside the file as it looks in your question?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes correct it has spaces, you can refer the file abc.lst in question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read line by line in the file into a `std::string`. You can then use the `string`s member function `find` to find what you're looking for.

When you've found `Cable_pull1.sh` for example, you loop, again using `std::getline`, and print the lines that follows until an empty line is found.

Example:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool findWord(std::string Filename, std::string const& find) {
    std::cout << "Filename:" << Filename << "\tfind:" << find << '\n';
    std::ifstream iFile(Filename.c_str());
    if(!iFile) {
        std::cerr << "File not opened!\n";
        return false;
    }

    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(iFile, line)) {     // read a whole line
        // and find "find" in that line
        std::size_t pos = line.find(find);

        // if "find" is found (pos != std::string::npos),
        // check that it's a full match to the rest of the line
        if(pos != std::string::npos && line.substr(pos) == find) {

            // ok, we found the correct entry in the file
            // loop and print each line (except the "MH_TEST" lines)

            while(std::getline(iFile, line)) {
                if(line.size()==0) break;           // empty line, break out
                if(line.find("MH_TEST") == std::string::npos) {
                    // print lines not matching MH_TEST
                    std::cout << line << '\n';
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    if(!findWord("abc.lst", "Cable_pull1.sh"))
        std::cout << "failed\n";
    else
        std::cout << "success\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Filename:abc.lst        find:Cable_pull1.sh
       DUAL_DOMAIN         yes
       CAMARO_STORAGE      YES
success
```

Comment: is it possible to do, if my 2 parameter ```find``` in function```findWord``` is empty . Then to list all the file contents

Comment: @AmithKotian Sure. One simple way: `while(std::getline(iFile, line)) { if(find.empty()) std::cout << line << '\n'; else { ... the rest of the current function ... }` should work but you'd probably make that special case into a separate function or part of the function instead of doing inside the loop.